# making graph/map of functions/methods calls in c# code (visual studio 2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I have some c# projects in visual studio 2008, and I want to get graph (map? table?) of all methods calls. I want it static, not runtime (like "call stack"); any function - who calls it, and how many times, etc.

I can *Find All References* method after method, and copy each call to table or Graphviz file, but it will take few hours. Is there an automatic tool or plugin that can help?

Comment: You can use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), which is a commercial static analysis tool for .NET.

Comment: Any Visual Studio plugin for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I've used:

- NDepend (not free)
- [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) with [Tom Carter's DSM plugin](http://www.tom-carter.net/) (not open source, but free)